# SQL Generate Random Number

Tags: sql, database, oracle, random

I have this table X with only one column, A. How can I generate a random number in each row, within specific values? Let's say I want random numbers to be either 1, 2 or 999 (3 numbers), I would have a column B looking something like this:

```
A | B
-----
12| 1
33| 999
67| 1
20| 2
...
```

I've tried the `dbms_random` package but only to generate between 2 numbers, like this:

```
select X.*, round(dbms_random.value(1,2)) from X;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method using `case`:

```
select x.a,
       (case when rand < 2 then 1 when rand < 3 then 2 else 999 end) as b
from (select x.*,
             dbms_random.value(1, 4) as rand
      from x
     ) x;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the values you want (1, 2, 999, bla, bla, bla) in a table, and join into it in a random order, like:

```
create table x (a int);

insert into x values (12);
insert into x values (33);
insert into x values (67);
insert into x values (20);

create table y (z int);

insert into y values (1);
insert into y values (2);
insert into y values (999);

create table new_x as
select a,
       z
  from (select a,
               z,
               row_number() over(partition by a order by dbms_random.value) as rn
          from x
         cross join y)
 where rn = 1;

drop table x;

alter table new_x rename to x;
```

**Fiddle:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8cf70/1/0

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49b7c/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE X ( A ) AS
SELECT LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT A,
       CASE FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,4))
            WHEN 1 THEN 1
            WHEN 2 THEN 2
                   ELSE 999 END AS B
FROM   X
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49b7c/1/0)**:

```
|  A |   B |
|----|-----|
|  1 |   1 |
|  2 |   2 |
|  3 | 999 |
|  4 | 999 |
|  5 |   2 |
|  6 |   1 |
|  7 | 999 |
|  8 | 999 |
|  9 | 999 |
| 10 | 999 |
| 11 |   1 |
| 12 |   1 |
| 13 | 999 |
| 14 |   2 |
| 15 |   1 |
| 16 |   2 |
| 17 |   2 |
| 18 | 999 |
| 19 |   1 |
| 20 | 999 |
```